# Insert a symbol ">" between the characters in a list of strings

Tags: string, matlab, excel, insert, vba

I have a column in Excel like this:

```
ABC
BCD
BA
```

How can I put the symbols ">" between every letters in the strings? The expected output should be like this:

```
A>B>C
B>C>D
B>A
```

Or could we do this in Matlab ?

Answer (score 3):

A single line matlab solution would be:

```matlab
strjoin(cellstr(str(:)), '>')
```

**Explanation:**

- [`cellstr(str(:))`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html): converts the char array to a cell array
- [`strjoin`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html): joins all the cells with the given delimiter, i.e. `>`

Answer (score 2):

If you have only ASCII characters, you can try this simple UDF:

```
Function insertChar(s As String, c As String) As String
  insertChar = Join(Split(StrConv(s, vbUnicode), vbNullChar), c)
End Function
```

Test:

```
A1: abcd;'.
B1: =insertChar(A1, ">")   ----->   a>b>c>d>;>'>.>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working macro code

```
Sub gt()

Dim a As Integer, b As String, U(100) As String, J

b = Selection
a = Len(Selection)
Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select


For i = 1 To a

If i <> a Then
J = J & Mid(b, i, 1) & ">"
Else
J = J & Mid(b, i, 1)
End If

Next i

ActiveCell = J

End Sub
```

Comment: Here is the working code as my previous answer was causing confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question!  Try it this way.

```
Sub InsertCharacter()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim xChar As String
Dim index As Integer
Dim arr As Variant
Dim xValue As String
Dim outValue As String
Dim xNum As Integer

Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
xRow = Application.InputBox("Number of characters :", xTitleId, Type:=1)
xChar = Application.InputBox("Specify a character :", xTitleId, Type:=2)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (select range):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")
xNum = 1
For Each Rng In InputRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    outValue = ""
    For index = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
        If index Mod xRow = 0 And index <> VBA.Len(xValue) Then
            outValue = outValue + VBA.Mid(xValue, index, 1) + xChar
        Else
            outValue = outValue + VBA.Mid(xValue, index, 1)
        End If
    Next
    OutRng.Cells(xNum, 1).Value = outValue
    xNum = xNum + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a custom function that takes in the value, loops through and places the characters, from the looks of it you want to skip when the character is a space... I also added the ability to change the character you are inserting on the fly, rather than hard coding. Something like:

```
Public Function AddGTSigns(strIn As String, strCharToAdd As String) As String
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim lngCount As Integer
    Dim lngLength As Integer
    Dim strNextChar As String
    lngLength = Len(strIn)

    For lngCount = 1 To lngLength
        strOut = strOut & Mid(strIn, lngCount, 1)
        If lngCount < lngLength Then
            'Check next character'
            If Mid(strIn, lngCount, 1) <> " " Then
                strOut = strOut & strCharToAdd
            End If
        End If
    Next lngCount

    AddGTSigns = strOut

End Function

Private Sub RunIt()
    Dim strTest As String

    strTest = AddGTSigns("ABC CDE GHE", ">")

    MsgBox strTest
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In complete case of the other answers, you can load the file in matlab an change the string by `strjoin`:

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread(fileName);
num = length(raw{:,1});
for rawNum = 1:num
    str = raw{rawNum,1};
    raw{rawNum,1} = strjoin(cellstr(str(:)), '>');
end 
xlswrite(fileName, raw);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the words are of same length, you can directly use the formula :-

MID(A1,1,1)&">"&MID(A1,2,2)&">".....

This will extract the characters and insert ">" between them.

If the words aren't of the same length, you can write a simple macro. The pseudo-code would be :-

for i = 1 to len(string)

Range("B1")=mid(A1,i,i)&">"

next i

and then remove the last > sign using left(txt,len(txt)-1).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good first answer! Using uppercase I as a variable name might be confusing, also it doesn't look like you're using this variable. Can you clarify how to remove the last > symbol?

Comment: uppercase or lowercase doesn't matter in vba. You can just write left(txt,len(txt)-1) for removing the last symbol.

Comment: I mean "I" might be confused as a lowercase L or the number one. Your psuedocode still isn't correct, as you're not using the variable anywhere. Please edit your answer.

Comment: thanks. I have used lowercase I. I myself got confused between 1 and I :)

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB (requires 17a for double quotes and 16b for strip/replace)

```
>> str = ["ABC"; "BCD"; "BA"];
>> str = strip(replace(str,'','>'),'>')

str = 

  3×1 string array

    "A>B>C"
    "B>C>D"
    "B>A"
```

Regexprep will work for older versions of MATLAB too

```
>> str = {'ABC';'BCD';'BA'};
>> str = regexprep(str,'(.)(?=.)','$1>')

str =

  3×1 cell array

    {'A>B>C'}
    {'B>C>D'}
    {'B>A'  }
```

Comment: what if str is a cell-array?

Comment: for the first line, there is an error: "Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions"

Comment: strip and replace will work on cellstrs. Double quotes for string creation were added in 17a and strip/replace were added in 16b. If you are using a version from before 16b, OmG looks to have the right solution.

Comment: Added regexprep example too.